# Hiding <div> in laravel 7

Tags: php, html, laravel

In my home.blade.php file I have several div-s.And if the {{$user[0]->d1}} is 1 then the div must be hidden.But I have no idea how to do that.

```
 {{$user[0]->d1}} //I want to have "if $user[0]->d1 == 1 ,then disable the following div
           <div>Text 1</div>
```

Is it even possible(I don't want to use gates or cans)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: You can actually also use the `@unless` directive which better translates your logic so you don't have to reverse the logic...

```
@unless ($user[0] == 1)
    <div>Text 1</div>
@endunless
```

---

**Other solution with `@if` directive:**

You can simply use the `@if` directive like this:

```
@if ($user[0]->d1 != 1)
    <div>Text 1</div>
@endif
```

Or even better (in case `$user[0]` might not exist):

```
@if (!isset($user[0]->d1) || $user[0]->d1 != 1)
    <div>Text 1</div>
@endif
```